# frida - hook socket inputstream in android apk

Tags: frida

I found InputStream hook code [here](https://github.com/iddoeldor/frida-snippets#hook-io-inputstream)! but I add below code in android, then try to hook it with the frida script, it's not been triggered:

Java code ([SocketDemo.apk](https://github.com/wjj1928/sharefolder/blob/master/SocketDemo.apk?raw=true)):

```
  InputStream ios = sock.getInputStream();
  int len = ios.read(dataBuf);
```

frida script.js:

```
function buf2hex(array, readLimit) {
    var result = [];
    var ascii = ""
    readLimit = readLimit || array.length;
    for (var i=0; i<readLimit;++i) {
        var elem = array[i] & 0xFF
        var str = (0x100 + elem).toString(16).substr(1)
        result.push(str);

        if (elem < 127 && elem >= 32) {
            ascii += String.fromCharCode(elem)
        } else {
            ascii += "."
        }
    }
    return result.join(' ') + " | " + ascii
}

function hookInputStream() {
    Java.use('java.net.Socket')['connect'].overload('java.net.SocketAddress').implementation = function(sockaddr) {
        console.log("connect")
        var retval = this.connect(sockaddr)
        return retval
    }
    Java.use('java.io.InputStream')['read'].overload('[B').implementation = function(data) {
        var retval = this.read(data)
        console.log("----" + data.length)
        var hexstr = buf2hex(data)
        console.log(hexstr)
        return retval
    }
}

Java.perform(hookInputStream);
```

command:

```
frida -Uf com.example.socketdemo -l script.js --no-pause
```

Comment: @Robert My call signature is byte[] only, no other arguments, I try to overload all read api and no luck!

Comment: it should work, either provide the apk or logcat

Comment: Your script works without problems, it does not work for you then this is most likely caused by the apk file you are hooking.

Comment: @i.e. Thanks, SocketDemo.apk download link updated, I add a connect hook also, the line printed but no any read logs!

Comment: @Robert post the SocketDemo.apk, connect can be hooked but read can not. I guess this FileInputStream is get from socket but not created by app!